# Create new command python

Tags: python, pythontex, sagetex

I want create a new command in python, in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234232/153360 add the command sage to pythontex. How can I change or add a command which output a string 
instead of a latex code?
I try whith

```
SubCodeEngine('python', 'sage', language='sage', extension='.sage',
              template=python_template.replace('{future}', ''),
              extend = 'pytex.formatter = str',
              commands='{sage} {file}.sage')
```

But when I run the code, the programm says that the control sequence is undefined.

**Edit**

I can partial solve it. If we change, in the pythontex_engines.py, the sage code for:

```
SubCodeEngine('python', 'sage', language='sage', extension='.sage',
                 template=python_template.replace('{future}', ''),
                 extend = 'pytex.formatter',
                 commands='{sage} {file}.sage')
```

When we use sage{somecode} we get a string code for us expressions, and for the command sage{latex(somecode)} we get the latex code of this.

Maybe it help anyone.